# Cannot find '.exec_blind' in object /KLauncher at org.kde.klauncher

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, kde-plasma

I recently rebooted my ubuntu environment (kde-plasma, running ubuntu 18.04), and now I'm having trouble launching a command I had previously aliased.  I typed the command itself manually, and get this issue:

`Cannot find '.exec_blind' in object /KLauncher at org.kde.klauncher`

Command ran was: `qdbus org.kde.klauncher /KLauncher exec_blind "/usr/bin/dolphin" "/home/username"`

I cannot seem to figure out via google fu or otherwise how to go about fixing this.

Any suggestions?  I know that it worked prior to reboot, and I know the command should in theory exist still.

[Link](https://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kinit/html/classKLauncher.html) to KLauncher class api from kde.  The method exists, but I've no idea why my setup is confused.

[Link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=136064) to where I originally had the idea to launch dolphin via dbus/ sourced my modified script from.

Answer (score 1):

The correct commmand is the following:

```
qdbus org.kde.klauncher5 /KLauncher exec_blind "/usr/bin/dolphin" "/home/username"
```